# Diferentiating between interna and external Angle in a cycle directed edge list

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I've got a cycle list of directed edges that delimite an interior and exterior and of course I can get the small angle between any consecutive edges with the dot product definition with $cos(\alpha) = {{u·v}\over{|u|·|v|}}$

But I was wondering if I there's an easy way of being sure I'm always getting the interior (or exterior angle subtracting $2\pi$) given that I've got an orientation.

Maybe looking $sign(<u \times v, \vec n>)$ with $\vec n$ the gradient to the surface where those edges lie?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, checking for the sign worked perfectly! ^^